# SOAP: issues with 2 different endpoint of the same WSDL function for the same PHP code

Tags: c#, php, soap, wsdl

Following 2 WSDLs works fine when tested with SOAP UI application.

I get two different outputs when tested with same code when calling the both WSDLs.

But I'm unable to figure out why the reason is. Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?
The WSDLs are developed in C#. The code I use for calling is PHP 5.6

We are moving from one server to cloud server. Existing server endpoint works fine. But in cloud server endpoint its not.

```
$url = <URL>

 $context = stream_context_create(
              array(
                 'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true,            
                ),
                'http'=>array(
                        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                )
            ));



 $client = new SoapClient($url,
            array(
                'stream_context' => $context,
                'trace' => 1,
                'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
                'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                'encoding' => SOAP_LITERAL,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'ssl_method ' => 
  array(SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv2,SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3),                               
            ));            

 var_dump($client);
```

If I pass URL as "http://www.postaplus.net/APIService/PostaWebClient.svc?wsdl" I get following object.

```
object(SoapClient)[1]
 public 'trace' => int 1
 public '_stream_context' => resource(2, stream-context)
 public '_soap_version' => int 1
 public 'sdl' => resource(8, Unknown)
```

But if I pass URL as "http://132.145.10.102:802/APIservice/postawebclient.svc?wsdl" then I get following error.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: <message> 'IPostaWebClient_Pickup_Creation_InputMessage' in C:\wamp64\www\soap_project\soap_obj.php on line 30
( ! ) SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: <message> 'IPostaWebClient_Pickup_Creation_InputMessage' already defined in C:\wamp64\www\soap_project\soap_obj.php on line 30
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  243136  {main}( )   ...\soap_obj.php:0
2   0.0007  246904  SoapClient ( )  ...\soap_obj.php:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out 2 solutions.

One is a work around and the second one is a silly solution.

I'll first explain the work around. According to following thread use 
http://...?singlewsdl instead of http://...?wsdl

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/db34ca67-cf57-4938-9657-cafd1edc4222/version-9-soap-errors-while-parsing-schema?forum=BingAds

So "http://www.postaplus.net/APIService/PostaWebClient.svc?singlewsdl" works fine.

The second and silly solution is.. use case sensitive URL!!

Changing URL from http://132.145.10.102:802/APIservice/postawebclient.svc?wsdl to 
http://132.145.10.102:802/APIservice/PostaWebClient.svc?wsdl solved my problem!